# passing multiple parameters as input using txt/xml file for android mobile app automation using uiautomator?

Tags: android-uiautomator

Can you please provide the details about passing multiple parameters as input using txt/xml file for android mobile app automation using uiautomator?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add a [mcve] detailing the code you have tried thus far. Explain why it does not work and what the expected results are.

Comment: Take a look at this tool [uiautomator-bot](http://uiautomator-bot.blogspot.com) . This tool may help you.